# How to write a query that gives the names of everyone who does not own a blue house?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Q. Write a query that gives the names of everyone who does not own a blue house.**

Here is my code:

```
SELECT persons.name
FROM persons
JOIN houses ON (persons.id=houses.owner_id)
WHERE houses.color<>'Blue';
```

The two tables are shown below:

[image]

My result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

How do I keep "Arian" from coming in my results?

"Arian" owns two houses, one red and one blue. Because of the red house he owns, he comes up on my results. I am struggling to figure out how to exclude him.

Comment: Please replace the screenshots with text in code blocks. See: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM persons p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM houses h
                  WHERE h.owner_id = p.id AND
                        h.color = 'Blue'
                 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate your fast and high quality answer. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @AspiringDeveloper. Kindly, you can accept the answer ( seems it helped ).

Answer (score 2):

We can also use aggregation to solve your problem:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM person p
INNER JOIN houses h
    ON p.id = h.owner_id
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING SUM(h.color = 'Blue') = 0;
```

Note that the performance of this approach would be similar to Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *anti-join*:

```
SELECT persons.name
FROM persons
LEFT JOIN houses
  ON  persons.id   = houses.owner_id
  AND houses.color = 'Blue'
WHERE houses.owner_id IS NULL
```